# How to add custom script on the header in magento2?

Tags: magento2, javascript

I want to include the js file on the header of the page. But I have selected the 'Move JS code to the bottom of the page' configuration from the admin panel. I want to include one specific script load on the header.

I have tried to include the Magento_Theme/default_head_blocks.xml file. Still, it's loading on the footer. How to add this file on the header. Any other option in code? Please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to add a script in cms page on all pages?

Comment: @WaqarAli yes. I have added a script for spam email. So it should be included in the header section.

Comment: please see my answer

Comment: @Emily check this https://www.dckap.com/blog/exclude-script-from-magento-2-3/

Comment: @BilalUsean I have seen this. In default Magento, there is no option for this? If no, I will try the above link.

Comment: What is your magento version? & what is configuration value of 'Move JS code to the bottom of the page'?

Comment: @RohanHapani Magento version 2.4.0 and 'Move JS code to the bottom of the page: yes

Comment: You need to create plugin for that. or need to override file. There are no default funtion of magento that exclude one single file to move in bottom.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add this Script on you whole website

then go to

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

at this code before `<body>` tag

```
<head>
     <link src="https://yourscriptlink.com/js_fileName.js"/>
</head>
```

Comment: I have tried the above method as well. But still, it's loading on the footer. Since But I have selected the 'Move JS code to the bottom of the page' configuration from the admin panel. Is there any other way to include jsfile on the head?

Comment: check my updated answer please

Comment: Please check my question. I have mentioned this. Tried with both the default.xml and dafault_head_blocks.xml files. But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy require_js.phtml from `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/page/js` to your theme `app/design/frontend/{VENDOR}/{THEME_NAME}/Magento_Theme/templates/page/js/`
2. Now you can add your script like this:

   ```
    console.log(""I'm loaded!"");

    var require = {
        ""baseUrl"": ""<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('/') ?>""
    };
   ```